# Pass optional filenames and variables into a Python function if optional kwarg set

Tags: python

I have tried to find a similar question/answer to this but struggled to put any of the answers into this problem, hopefully someone could help.

I have a function that reads in a filename `data_dir/filename`, extracts a `data_var` from the file, and also reads in additional parameters in `**kwargs`. There are default `filename` and `dat_var` that must be read in, and the function would look like

```py
def function(data_dir, filename, data_var, **kwargs):
  # some code
```

However, I would like the option of adding in `filename2` and `data_var2`, which must also be accompanied with a `**kwargs` for computations to be done on the additional data.

For example, I would define `kwargs = {"lflag" : True}` and read in the extra data, the function would look like

```py
def function(data_dir, filename, data_var, filename2, data_var2, **kwargs):
  
  # default flag
  opt_dic = {"lflag"  : False}

  for key in kwargs:
    opt_dic[key] = kwargs[key]

  # load in filename and read data_var
  ds = Dataset(data_dir + filename)
  var = ds.variables[data_var][...]
  ds.close()

  # load in filename2 and read data_var2
  if opt_dic["lflag"]:
    ds2 = Dataset(data_dir + filename2)
    var2 = ds2.variables[data_var2][...]
    ds2.close()

  # some more code
```

But how would I define `filename2` and `data_var2` as optional arguments that can be left out of the function when not needed?

Examples of calling this function in default state,

```py
kwargs = {}
output = function(data_dir, filename, data_var, **kwargs):
```

and with additional data

```py
kwargs = {"lflag" : True}
output = function(data_dir, filename, data_var, filename2, data_var2, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just do `filename2="default value"` and `data_var2="another default value"?

Comment: I want to have the option of leaving the two additional input arguments out of the function when they are not needed. I have updated the last sentence of the question.

Comment: Do you have some examples of how you'd like to call these? I must be misunderstanding you. My comment refers to the _arguments_ of the function, not the call itself

Comment: I have updated the question with a few examples of the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using only one `filename` and only one `data_var` parameter in any case. Thus, the respective arguments could be strings or lists of two strings. For example, implementing this idea for the `filename` could start like this:

```py
def function(data_dir, filename, data_var, **kwargs):
    
    filename2 = None
    
    if type(filename) == list:
        
        if len(filename) != 2:
            raise ValueError('filename lists must have exactly two elements.')
        
        filename, filename2 = filename
        
    print(filename, filename2)
    
    # ...

 
function('/a/', ['f1', 'f2'], 'v1')
>>> f1 f2
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of ***args** and ****kwargs** in your method signature.

```
def function(data_dir, filename, data_var, *args, **kwargs)
   data_dir = "method argument"
   filename = "method argument"
   data_var = "method argument"
   args     = [] # an iterable
   kwargs   = {} # a dictionary key/value pair
   print(data_dir, filename, data_var)
   print(args)
   print(kwargs)
```

Output example

```
>>> function("/tmp", "test.txt", "var-test", "test2.txt", "var2-test", test="arguments-keyvalue") 
/tmp test.txt var-test 
('test2.txt', 'var2-test') 
{'test': 'arguments-keyvalue'}
```

Real Python explain: [here](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the kwargs flag; You can just do something along the lines of this

```
def function(data_dir, filename, data_var, filename2=None, data_var2=None):
    # always perform computations on data_dir and filename
    ds = Dataset(data_dir + filename)
    var = ds.variables[data_var][...]
    ds.close()

    # if filename2 was passed, assume data_var2 was passed
    if not (filename2 is None):
        ds2 = Dateset(data_dir + filename)
        var2 = ds2.variables[data_var2][...]
    
    # some more code
    ...
```

Here's a minimal example to demonstrate this

```
def f(x,y=None)
    print(x) # always executed

    if not(y is None):
        print(y)

f(1) # prints 1
f(1,2) # prints 1 and 2, separated by newlines
```